# How to remove context menu options not shown on application selection

Tags: menu

Whenever I right click a HTML, CSS, JS or PHP file I get the following:

[image]

As you can see I have several options that do not show in the "Recommended Applications" window. I wish to eliminate all options that do not appear in the Recommended Application windows. In this case, the following are the ones I want to eliminate:

Google Docs
LibreOffice Writer
SciTE Text Editor
notepad